# No more Hot Questions?

Tags: bug, hot-questions

Till about 20 minutes back I used to get a "Hot on Meta" on the right side. This has reduced to only "Featured questions".

[image: No Hot]

Where can I find the Hot questions? Or is it deliberately removed?

**EDIT:**

The Hot Meta Post is back but from the linked to question [What happened to the Hot Meta Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts?lq=1) this has happened again.

Comment: Meta cooled down, that's all. Move on people, move on...

Comment: I can still see it. Perhaps normal service has resumed!

Comment: @worldofjr Please see the duplicate question. Thanks.

Comment: I saw your profile. How did you get that link to always go to the user's home screen? It's cool! Let me know, I wanna do that too!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Use the link http://stackoverflow.com/users/current ... But no copying the idea. OK?

Comment: Lol, I would never copy [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current) person's idea! :-)

Comment: Did you make that link? Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5144855/ruchir-baronia

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Naw. It was made by the Stack Overflow devs.