# What happened to the Hot Meta Posts?

Tags: bug, hot-questions, community-bulletin

I just notice that the side bar that has the Featured on Meta and the Hot Meta Posts now only has Featured on Meta section.

[image]

What happened to the Hot Meta Posts?

**EDIT:**

The Hot Meta Post is back but from the linked to question [No more Hot Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311903/no-more-hot-questions?lq=1) this has happened before.

The Hot Meta Post has been missing at the following times(UTC):

- Dec  7 at 20:51
- Dec  9 at 17:24
- Dec 11 at 10:00,17:13
- Dec 13 at 22:19
- Dec 14 at 03:17,12:50,21:09
- Dec 15 at 01:00
- Jan 27 at 22:45

<sup>Please edit this list if you find other times this happens</sup>

**EDIT 2:**

<strike>The issue has not happened again for some time.  It appears to be resolved.  If there was an issue that caused it a it would be nice to know what it was.</strike> This issue has come up [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts?noredirect=1#comment299733_312035).  I am not sure if it was a one off issue or we will see more of this again.

Comment: Now we need a meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Seems to be just SO, [other](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) [sites](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) [still](http://superuser.com/) have hot meta action.

Comment: Reported it a few days back. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311903/no-more-hot-questions It comes back after 30 minutes. So after that it will be closed as no repro :-(

Comment: @BhargavRao Well it did happen again so it is something that was reproducible.  I am going to leave this up so the devs can look at it if they chose to.

Comment: @BhargavRao Can I leave my witty comment again?

Comment: @rene There is always room for a witty comment on meta.

Comment: Bu .u.u. But my image had free hand circles :D

Comment: Breaking news: *Stack Overflow's contribution to climate change paid off*

Comment: I blame all of the tag burninating on that ;)

Comment: *gasp* they are back!

Comment: OMG, we should ask them where they were. cc@Braiam.

Comment: It's funny because this question itself is in the hot meta posts: 
http://snag.gy/9f5lW.jpg

Comment: Voting to reopen as it has occurred again http://imgur.com/KXCpRKF.png

Comment: It is the third time today. @NathanOliver Can you edit your post to add the logs?

Comment: @BhargavRao I do not have logs but I did add a list of times when it was missing that I know of.

Comment: Also un*featured* [posts](http://i.imgur.com/iJHHyk7.png) are showing up in featured positions

Comment: It's gone again for me. UTC 22:39 DEC 13 2015.