# I like the number of Hot Meta Posts shown

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

In the past when there were a lot of blog posts or featured content in the side panel, sometimes Hot Meta Posts got [left](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336870/minimum-number-of-hot-meta-posts-not-shown) [out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts) or there was only one. After I had finished reading all the featured content, the side panel became rather boring.

Today I noticed that three hot meta posts were being shown, even though a number of other featured content items were present. I like that and I don't think it makes the panel too big. Thanks. I hope this format will stay.

[image]

Comment: MSE featured doesn't count against the 4 items. Currently, the 4 slots are filled by 1 blog + 3 hot meta post.